# Matplotlib graph changes first Y-axis value if startingpoint is moved to 1 on X-Axis

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, graph

Disclaimer: english isnt my first language. if you have a better idea for a title, please tell me! thanks.

Hi, i want to plot a graph of word frequencies with matplotlib. While doin so i discovered that the graph changes the first value depending on how i define the values for the x-axis. Why does that happen?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y=[0.016863998744448577, 0.015003092169058504, 0.014825596059960054, 0.010577522515537138, 0.009747338959648594, 0.008714747560051294, 0.007646656938634301, 0.007539536479809973, 0.007245578011408329, 0.007138457552584001]   
x = list(range(1,11))        #1 try
#x = list(range(len(y)))     #2 try

plt.yscale('log')
plt.xscale('log')
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

option #1 for x gives the following graph. The graph starts at x=1 and y=0.0168... seems right 
[image: the graph starts at x=1 and y=0.0168... seems right]

option #2 for x gives another graph. Here it starts with x=0 but y=0.0150... doesnt seem right 
[image: here it starts with x=0 but y=0.0150... doesnt seem right]

somehow in my second option the graph uses the same y-value at least 2 times. why does it do that?

Comment: In the first try `x` includes numbers from 1 to 10, while in the second try you start with 0.  `range` starts at 0 by default, so you have values from 0 to 9 in your `x` in the second try.

Comment: @Ardweaden my first try is 1-11. how is it any different if i have my first value pair as (0, 0.016863998744448577) to having the first pair as (1, 0.016863998744448577)? that makes no sense to me. the last would be (10, 0.007138457552584001) and (11,  0.007138457552584001). i just move the starting point of the graph to +1 on the x axis. how does that change the first y-value?

Comment: You are using a log scale so it gets rescaled differently. I'm surprised you're not getting a warning given log(0) is undefined. I can give an example: Imagine your x values are 0.0001 and 1.0. If you use a logarithmic scale, the first one will be at -4 and the second one at 0. However if you shift by 0.1 -> 0.1001,1.1. Then the first one will be at roughly -1 and the second one at roughly 0.

Comment: What is log(0) again...?

Comment: ok. so that seems to be the problem. does that mean that i have to start the graph at x=1 to work properly?

Comment: @Ardweaden matplotlib by default discards coordinates that are -inf, +inf, or nan without warning.

Comment: Both are actually correct. `log(0)` is really interpreted as minus infinity, hence the horizontal line at the start. Which option to chose depends on your data and what it is meant to depict.

Comment: as showing the first value is quite important for me (its for a zipf function), i will start my graph a 1. Thanks for the help guys!